# Google Analytics Data API (GA4) in R - Filters with "IF" statement

Tags: r, if-statement, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I want to get data from GA Data API (GA4) in R using ga_data_filter:

```
ga_query <- tryCatch({ga_data(ga_id[i],
dimensions = c("yearMonth", "Country", "sessionSourceMedium"),
metrics = c("sessions", "totalUsers"),
dim_filters = ga_data_filter("sessionSourceMedium" %contains% 
df_project$Source[i] & !"landingPagePlusQueryString" %regex% df_project$Landing[i]) & (if (df_project$Source[i] == "google.com") "Country" == "USA" else TRUE) & (if (df_project$Source[i] == "google.com") "sessionSourceMedium" == "google / organic" else TRUE)),
limit = -1,
date_range = c("2023-08-01", format(last_day_of_previous_month, "%Y-%m-%d")))}, error = function(e) {return(NULL)  # Return NULL in case of an error})
```

It seems ga_data_filter doesn’t work with “If” and when I do it through a variable it doesn’t work either. Maybe somebody faced with such query and issue.